Efficiently Handling Job Queue and Thread Signaling in a Cross-Platform Thread Pool Library in C
I am trying to make a cross platform threadpool library in c.
The thing that I don't understand is that for example if I have 4 threads in the threadpool and I give all 4 of them work to do and its going to take a long time, in this case 1 minute, if I add 20 jobs into the jobqueue before the 1 minute mark, all 20 function call will signal for threads when they add anything into queue but no thread will be able to get that signal (as no threads are waiting for any signals). And the signal would be lost. When any of the threads are free they will wait indefinitely because there would be no more signals as all jobs are already in the queue.
here is an example code
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile int job[10];
volatile int job_counter = 0;
pthread_mutex_t job_mutex;
pthread_cond_t job_cond;

void *worker_func(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&job_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&job_cond, &job_mutex);
        printf("here2\n");
        printf("work doing %d\n", job[job_counter]);
        sleep(3);
        if(job_counter++==10){
            break;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&job_mutex);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_cond_init(&job_cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&job_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker_func, NULL);
    printf("here1\n");
    sleep(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&job_mutex);
        job[i]=i;
        pthread_cond_signal(&job_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&job_mutex);
    }
    sleep(2);
    printf("here3\n");
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

if you want specificity and source of my problem take a look here
https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool/issues/132 
Any help would be appreciated.

I think, you have to implement the queue (FIFO) as a variaible protected by a mutex.


all 20 function call will signal for threads when they add anything into queue but no thread will be able to get that signal (as no threads are waiting for any signals). And the signal would be lost.

You are using your condition variable incorrectly (or planning to do so).
A condition variable must always be associated with a testable predicate (a condition) that must be true for a thread to proceed past a given point.  For example, "the task queue is not empty".  A thread arriving at that point first evaluates the predicate, under protection of the mutex.  Only if the predicate evaluates false does it wait on the CV.  Furthermore, after it returns from its wait, the thread must cycle back and again test whether the condition is satisfied, and possibly then go back to waiting.
Yes, there might not be a thread ready to run a new task as soon as it is submitted, so it might be that none is awakened by the signal to the CV.  But that does not prevent the task from being taken, because receiving the signal is just a way to tell threads that they may need to take notice of a relevant state change, such as a task having been added to the queue.  It should not itself be the way that your threads learn that there is work to be done.

so i found a really good way i could just check first if there are any jobs in the queue and if there are none then wait. when the job is pushed, then broadcast the signal. then how to know when to destroy the pool after all the jobs are finished, i could just check the jobqueue length and the working threads, if they are not working and jobqueue length is 0 then destroy. is this the best way?

@neo, when to shut down the pool is not a function of the pool itself.  It's a matter of whether you need it any more, which is to say, whether you anticipate having any more tasks for it.  When that time comes, you probably need to use some kind of flag in addition to the task queue to tell the threads to terminate, as the queue being empty now is not necessarily a reliable sign that there won't be any more tasks in the future.
